# Can the partial derivative of f(x,y) at (a,b) exist if f(x,y) is not continuous at (a,b)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose f(x,y) is continuous for all $(x,y) \neq (a,b)$, (not continuous at (a,b)), can the partial derivative with respect to x (or y) at (a,b) still exist?

Comment: where at (a,b)?If it is so, It will not exist at (a,b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, look at this example:

$f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$, though the partial derivatives exist, as you can show

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2-y^2} &, x\neq  \pm y \\ 0 &, x = \pm y \end{cases}$

The Jacobian Matrix exists at $(0,0)$, (use definition to show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist).

Comment: This function is not continous at all $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.

Comment: "(not continuous at (a,b))", that's what user110617 says. You are right though.

Comment: What I meant is that the question starts out with "Suppose $f(x,y)$ is continuous for all $(x,y) \neq (a,b)$", and this requirement is not satisfied by your example.

Comment: Just to show that the partials derivatives exist, that was the first example that came to mind, as I said you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Another example is 
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} & \text{ if}\  (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 0 & \text{ if}\  (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$$